# How do I exclude certain sheets/tabs from google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this code: `function onEdit(e) { e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('K2').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss") }`

to add the date and time when each sheet/tab was 'last updated', however, there are two tabs I want to exclude from this: "Product Features" and "Client List Overview" - how can I adjust the script so that these two tabs/sheets are not included? (I'm complete novice so will need to know exactly what to change and where to put it, thank you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var excl = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];//excluded sheets
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (!~excl.indexOf(activeSheet.getSheetName())) {
    activeSheet.getRange('K2').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
  }
}
```

[Bitwise NOT (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Answer (score 0):

Consider get first the name of the active sheet, then, add an conditional to check if the name of the active sheet is *different* from the ones you want to exclude the code (*i.e. setting a date in a specific cell*).

Example (*N.B: untested*):

```
function onEdit(e) {
    /** Name of the active sheet. */
    var sheetName = "";

    /** Active sheet. */
    var activeSheet = null;

    // Get active sheet: 
    activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

    // Get active sheet's name:
    sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();

    // Apply this code to those active sheets where their name is different from these sheets:
    if (sheetName != "Product Features" && sheetName != "Client List Overview") {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('K2').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  activeSheet.getRange('K2').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss") 
  }
```